# How to import a python class/module in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

example contrived for this question. apologize for basic question. I have following code/directory structure

```
src
  - main.py
my_notebook.ipynb
```

main.py

```
class DoSomething():
  pass
```

I have seen various questions in stackoverflow, which suggest this should work in my notebook,

my_notebook.ipynb

```
from src.main import DoSomething
...
```

when i run this notebook , i get Module not found error : No module named 'src.main': 'src' is not a package. Although, i knew this wouldn't work but i tried to move main.py to the root of my project and tried

```
from main import DoSomething
```

I get similar error -> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DoSomething'

Answer (score 1):

add an empty `__init__.py` file in your directory.
Then just simply write:

```
from main import DoSomething
```